# wp_postmeta or custom table?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

For each inserted row in wp_posts, I need to add 2 custom fields in wp_postmeta (especially one of this 2 fields can be a little bit redundant, because if it is connected to a the same group of posts the meta value is always the same).

I know for sure that to add columns in wp_posts is not the solution.

I was wondering if it was more convenient create a custom table that contains those 2 fields or keep them in the wp_postmeta table.

Comment: That's exactly what the `postmeta` table is for...

Comment: Yes I know, but I was thinking that in my own custom table I could add in one row all the custom fields that I want, instead in wp_postmeta I should add a new row for each custom field. Is this making no difference at all?

Comment: It depends on what you plan on doing with that meta data. You could also save the data as an array in `wp_postmeta` (in one meta field), to keep it all in one row.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was not considering that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the postmeta table. When dealing with WordPress, it's best to stick with the WordPress method of things unless you really have a good reason for not.